# What is wrong with this mysql connection string?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, connection-string

I am using this connection string,

```
<add name="connectionString" connectionString="server=10.1.1.16;user id=root;
password=lmslive; database=lmslive; pooling=false;" 
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

and this database `lmslive` is in a system next to mine connected via proxy.... And i executed this query on that system,

```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON lmslive.* TO 'lmslive'@'10.1.1.15'
    IDENTIFIED BY 'lmslive' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I get the error,

`Access denied for user 'root'@'XAVY-PANDIYA' (using password: YES)`.. Any suggestion? what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `user id=root` with `user id=lmslive` in your `connectionString`.

Comment: @asaph when i give that `Unable to retrieve stored procedure metadata.  Either grant  SELECTprivilege to mysql.proc for this user or use "use procedure bodies=false" with  your connection string.`

Comment: It sounds like your perms are a bit messed up.

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: The error message is telling you exactly what to do next. You have 2 choices: 1) Run a statement like `GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO 'lmslive'@'10.1.1.15' IDENTIFIED BY 'lmslive'`. or 2) Set the `use procedure bodies=false` option.

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: Glad to hear that. Please mark this answer as correct :)