# ASP.NET configuration with MySQL database?

Tags: asp.net, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I setup ASP.NET MVC 2 with MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512852/how-do-i-setup-asp-net-mvc-2-with-mysql)

Hey guys I created and configured a mySQL database, and am using ASP.NET MVC framework. What is the connection string that I should use to connect with my database?

Can anyone suggest a tutorial or a book resource I could use?

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512852/how-do-i-setup-asp-net-mvc-2-with-mysql, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252949/what-is-wrong-with-this-mysql-connection-string

Answer (score 1):

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Database=xxxxx;User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxx;" providerName="MySQL.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.connectionstrings.com contains a list of most of the connectionstrings from different databases.

The MySQL section can be found here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19407/A-StepbyStep-Guide-To-Using-MySQL-with-ASPNET--Part-1.htm

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19493/A-StepbyStep-Guide-To-Using-MySQL-with-ASPNET--Part-2.htm